# Http to Https redirection for Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, ssl, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite. I have installed SSL and want to redirect from http to https for an example: http://behindtalkies.com/ to https://behindtalkies.com/ but it is not redirecting. I have read so many post here and added code in .htaccess but nothing helping me out. I'm not sure what mistake am doing.

Comment: Post your config file on what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have a multi-site .htaccess issue too.

The site c3summitllc.com should forward to c3summit2018.com and it does not. I cleared the browser before retrying or posting here. It is also a multi-site for these sites: http://www.c3summitllc.com/business2016/agenda/ and http://www.c3summitllc.com/healthcare2016/agenda/ and if I go to these sites and click Home it goes to the site www.c3summit2017.com which is wrong also.

Here is what I have right now. My goal is to get to the c3summit2018.com url for anything other than these site links and to get the Home button working correctly on the sites.

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.c3summit2018.com
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```